# How to formulate a query and view for the following structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the following table structure

### TableA

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
Ro1      A         1
Ro1      A         1
Ro7      A         3
Ro2      C         1
Ro3      B         1
Ro3      B         1
Ro6      B         2
Ro4      C         2
Ro5      A         2
```

> Task: Create the table stipulated above with Two column (ColumnA, ColumnB) , then develop a query/view that will produce the structure as shown in view above, of which ColumnC is found within a view and not within the table and its contents are automatically generated by considering changes of values in ColumnA and ColumnB respectively.

I simply don't understand how to formulate this query.

Comment: i assume because how the way this question is asked that this is a homework or job interview related question see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: *" I simply don't understand how to formulate this query."* i would suggest by starting to read the MySQL manual about the [CREATE VIEW Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)

Comment: If you have no PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table. Hence, the problem becomes one beyond the scope of relational databases.

Comment: I mostly use mysql but I kept oracle just to get an idea of the query and more viewers

Comment: to add to @APC 's comment, Hancy for a better understanding what the tags mean on this website i would suggest reading the description next time which you can read also when making the question.. it is clear that the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag has a warning not to use the tag for products owned by Oracle

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with the DENSE_RANK analytic function. This is available in MySQL since version 8.0. [Find out more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank).

```
 select columnA
        , columnB
        , dense_rank() over (partition by columnB order by columnA) as columnC
from tableA
```

Caveat: that's how it would be done in Oracle. I think the same syntax ought to work in MySQL too. However, the documentation shows something different. As I don't have a MySQL to play with right now I'm hedging my bets :)

```
 select columnA
        , columnB
        , dense_rank() over W as columnC
from tableA 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY columnB ORDER BY columnA);
```

The MySQL documentation covers how [to create a view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html).